# ругается на переменную

Tags: kotlin

выдает ошибку при попытке записать в переменную значение : This variable must either have a type annotation or be initialized

```
  private fun InitAuth () {
    // Retrieves the user's saved password for your app from their
// password provider.
    val getPasswordOption = GetPasswordOption()

// Get passkey from the user's public key credential provider.
   // val requestJson
     lateinit var requestJson
    val getPublicKeyCredentialOption = GetPublicKeyCredentialOption(
        requestJson = requestJson
    )

}
```

А если не объявлять переменную, то будет писать ошибку: Unresolved reference: requestJson

вот тут указано именно так написать - без указания значения и без указания типа и без инициализации пермеренной
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вы делаете запрос, нужно передать json запроса. Вместо этого вы пытаетесь создать пустую переменную и как бы надеетесь, что kotlin сам догадается, что вы там за json хотите передать.

Comment: `lateinit var requestJson` - у этой переменной `requestJson` нет ни конкретного типа, ни значения, а вы её передаёте параметром в функцию. Поэтому компилятор не понимает, что ему передавать в функцию, какое значение, если значения нет, и типа нет. Если бы был хотя бы тип, можно было бы инициализировать эту переменную значением по умолчанию хотя бы.

Comment: на сайте указано именно так написать - без указания значения и без указания типа и без инициализации пермеренной. Подскажете, значит неверно указано на сайте ?

Comment: На приведённом вами скриншоте в переменные без указания типа **присваиваются результаты работы функций**.  А в вашем куске кода хотя и указан знак `=`, но во-первых это присвоение значения параметру функции с таким именем, а не переменной, во-вторых переменная справа от знака `=` **должна иметь конкретное значение**, а у вас это переменная **без значения и типа**.

Comment: Kotlin язык со строгой типизацией. Нельзя без указания типа напрямую либо через явное присвоение значения обьявить переменную. https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-variables#0

Answer (score 0):

Давайте я разберу код по строкам прямо.

```
lateinit var requestJson
```

Объявляем переменную `lateinit var`, т.е. без типа и с поздней инициализацией, и не присваиваем ей ничего.

```
val getPublicKeyCredentialOption = GetPublicKeyCredentialOption(
        requestJson = requestJson
)
```

Здесь мы вызываем функцию `GetPublicKeyCredentialOption` и в качестве параметра функции под названием `requestJson` передаём нашу переменную `requestJson`. Тут название параметра функции и название переменной совпадают, но это не должно вас смущать. Можно заменить это понятным примером, который даст ту же самую ошибку:

```
lateinit var requestJson
val x = requestJson
```

Что мы тут хотим присвоить переменной `x`? Отсутствующее значение неизвестного типа. Если бы хотя бы тип переменной был известен, компилятору можно было бы инициализировать её значением по умолчанию для данного типа. Но в данном случае у компилятора нет вообще никаких подсказок, что же за значение должно быть в этой переменной и он вас прямо просит указать хотя бы одну из таких подсказок.

Надеюсь, так понятнее, откуда возникает ошибка.

P.S. Я `Kotlin` вообще не знаю, руководствуюсь знанием других языков программирования и здравым смыслом.